# copying a folder, renaming and incrementing value

Tags: batch-file, auto-increment

Basically I have a folder named "9999-0004 - PM Access Project Creation Template V2"
I want to copy it and rename it to "2019-#### - project name"
where #### is a number with leading zeros and project name is user input name.
My code works fine incrementing the value of #### however say I have:

```
2019-0015 - project number 1
2019-0016 - some other project
2019-0018 - a different value
2019-0019 - insert name here
```

when I ran the batch file I end up getting: 
    2019-0017 - rename this folder

what I want it to do is to rename it to:
    2019-0020 - rename this folder

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion


set source="C:\test1\9999-0004 - PM Access Project Creation Template V2"
set destination=C:\test2\

set /P project=please enter name of project:
set "n=0"

set "name=%project%"
set "year=2019"



pushd %destination%



:loop

set Var=0000%n%
set Var=%Var:~-4%

if exist %destination%\2019-%Var%* set /a n+=1 && goto :loop

set final_destination="%destination%2019-%Var% - %name%"
xcopy /s %source% %final_destination%\  /O /X /E /H /K

icacls %final_destination% /grant "MACStaff:(OI)(CI)(W)" 


popd

@echo on
```

Comment: Consider completely re-writing what you're asking. It's not very clear. I have no idea where to start because it just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off

setlocal

set "source=u:\sourcedir\t w o"
set "destination=u:\destdir"

SET "project=rename this folder"

set "year=2019"

SET /a var=10000

FOR /f "tokens=2delims=- " %%a IN ('dir /ad /on /b "%destination%\%year%-*" 2^>nul') DO set /a Var=1%%a + 1
set "final_destination=%destination%\%year%-%Var:~1% - %project%"
echo xcopy /s "%source%" "%final_destination%\"  /O /X /E /H /K

ECHO icacls "%final_destination%" /grant "MACStaff:(OI)(CI)(W)" 

GOTO :EOF
```

I used directorynames that suit my system.

I've also forced the new directoryname suffix input for testing purposes

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

Assigning quoted strings to variables make the variables hard to combine logically. Inserting quotes as needed is far simpler.

Note that this procedure does not require `delayedexpansion` (which it seems you weren't using anyway)

So - the principle is to read a directory listing in `/b` basic mode of the `/ad` directorynames only `/on` in name-order using a mask of `%year%-*`, that is all directorynames for the year in question.

Using delimiters of `-` and <kbd>Space</kbd>, the result will be that `%%a` acquires each serial-number in turn (Your format is yyyy<kbd>-</kbd>serial<kbd>Space</kbd>text so the second token containing the serial), so `var` appears with the last value found, with `1` prepended and 1 added.

If there are no matching directorynames, then the `2^>nul` suppresses the ugly error message (meaning send error messages to the `nul` device to dispose of them, and the caret (`^`) tells `cmd` that the redirector is part of the `dir` command to be executed, not of the `for`. `var` will remain unchanged, so it will retain the value `10000`.

Then construct `final_destination` Meccano-style and make yourself a cup of coffee.